# How can I make a variable retain old information?

Tags: javascript, html

So for example, let's say I define a variable as being equivalent to some text typed into a textarea then I change the text in the textarea to a new value. I want to be able to keep the old value stored in the variable originally and compare it with the new value stored. I thought maybe I could do this with two variables. What I want to do with the code is find out whether or not the value I entered originally is the same as the new value I enter or not. Here's an attempt. I don't expect the code below to work at all. It's only meant to give an idea of what I want to do.

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
<input onclick="MyFunction();" type="submit" value="submit"/> 

function MyFunction(){
    var MyVariable = document.getElementById("mytext").value();
    var MyVariable2 = document.getElementById("mytext").value();
    if(MyVariable === MyVariable2){
        alert('the text is the same');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('the text is different');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2eFD2/4/

Comment: Check the console in that fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make a variable retain old information?

By not assigning new information to it.

Simply create a variable *outside* of the function, so that it persists between function calls, and only assign to it if it doesn't have a value yet:

```
var previousValue = null;

function MyFunction(){
    var currentValue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

    if (previousValue === currentValue){
        alert('the text is the same');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('the text is different');
    }

    if (previousValue == null) {
        // only executed the first time the function is called
        previousValue = currentValue; 
    }
}
```

> I need the variable with the old information to lag behind the second variable with information the second variable had before being given new info.

Then you just always assign the new value to the variable:

```
var previousValue = null;

function MyFunction(){

    var currentValue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

    if(previousValue === currentValue){
        alert('the text is the same');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('the text is different');
    }

    previousValue = currentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use make use of the HTML5 data attribute:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("myText");
textArea.setAttribute("data-old", textArea.value());
```

And retrieve it with:

```
document.getElementById.getAttribute("data-old");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways that spring to mind:

1. If you have JQuery, you can use [data storage](http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/) to store the old value by attaching it to the textbox for example;
2. If you want to do it in an even simpler way, you could also have a hidden text box for each text box you want to track. Every time the main text box value changes, you can "save" the old value in the hidden text box.

Whatever you do, just avoid storing the old values in global variables as that will pollute your global namespace and that is never a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 `data` attribute or `localStorage` to hold the value.

*Data attribute:*

```
var myText = document.getElementById("myText");
myText.setAttribute("data-old", myText.value); //Set
myText.getAttribute("data-old");               //Get
```

*LocalStorage:*

```
localStorage.setItem("myText", document.getElementById("myText").value); //Set
localStorage.getItem("myText");                                          //Get
```

Comment: What is `$` and `.data`? They are not native JavaScript or DOM functions. Some library maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to assign your old variable data to new variable here is the fiddle:

Try This Code: var MyVariable2 = null;

```
function MyFunction(){
    var MyVariable = $("#mytext").val();

    if (MyVariable2 == null) {
        MyVariable2 = MyVariable; 
    }

    if(MyVariable === MyVariable2){
        alert('the text is the same');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('the text is different');
    }
}
```

here is the fiddle : `http://jsfiddle.net/2eFD2/6/`

Comment: Ok, how would I go about updating the variable retaining the old information with the newer information as the variable with the even newer information changes? Basically, I need the variable with the old information to lag behind the second variable with information the second variable had before being given new info.

Comment: So for example, in the fiddle you sent, If I type in "Something" the alert message will say "This text is the same". If I then type "Something Again", the alert message will say "This text is not the same" but now, I want it to be so that the variable is updated with "Something Again" so if I type "Something Again", again, it'll say "This text is the same" and if I type "Something Else" it'll say "this text is different".

Comment: I want it to continuously be like that every function call.

Comment: basically, I type "hey" then type "hey" again and I get a message saying "this text is the same". I then type "random text" and get "This text is different" then if I type "random text" again, I get "This text is the same" then if I type "whatever else" I get "This text different, then "whatever else" again I get "This text is the same. On and on.

Comment: why don't you use database for this issues? you can store value in db and then make some conditions to get the solution.

Comment: because I only need to save what was last typed as in my example above.

Comment: so, you can use Use COOKIE plugin like "$.cookie("example", "foo");": and i don't have that much knowledge of cookies in j query but it can be helpful for your code.

Comment: yes i refereed your answer but it was not returning something so i have made some changes on it.

Comment: @FelixKling He might have. Do you have a solution to what I'm describing above without resorting to a database?

Comment: @Brandon: Sure, check my updated answer (assuming I have correctly understood what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, I'm using that Old Value to check whether form get updated or not and on submit I'm removing unchanged input

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="Name" data-initial="Foo" value="Foo" />
    <input type="text" id="Location" data-initial="Bar" value="Bar" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#myform").submit( function() {
$(this).find("input").filter( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    return $this.data("initial") == $this.val();
}).remove();
});
```