# Need a simple adjustment made to this function with data retaining variable.

Tags: javascript

I recently posted a question asking for help with storing information in a variable. I was given an answer I that I thought solved my problems. It did, but there's one issue. First, here's the post and answer I was given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980101/2603319
TLDR: I wanted to have a textarea where you add a value like "hey" and press submit for example, it's stored in the variable as seen in the fiddle, and then if you type "hey" again for example, you'll receive a message that says "This text is the same". If you type something new like "Hello" after, you get the message, "This text is different" but if you type "Hello" again, you'll get the message "This text is the same". The code below and in the jsfiddle work fine however my issue is, the very first time you type anything into the textarea and submit, you get the message "This text is different". What can I do to keep that from happening yet keep the functionality I want?

Here's the code and jsfiddle for it:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="MyFunction();" type="button" value="submit"/>Submit</button>
var previousValue = null;
var currentValue = null;
function MyFunction(){

var currentValue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

if(previousValue === currentValue){
    alert('the text is the same');
}
else
{
    alert('the text is different');
}
previousValue = currentValue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2eFD2/9/

Comment: what do you want it to say when the text is initially inserted? or do you want no output at that point?

Comment: Yes, no input or I mean initially I don't want it to be true that previousValue is not equal to currentValue.

Comment: yup, ok check my answer, since it's set to null initially I just did a null check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have your function like this, to avoid output at the initial insert of a value by the user;

```
function MyFunction(){

   var currentValue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

   if(previousValue === null){
      //alert('first data entry'); //<-- you can put any code you want to happen when the user initially enters a value
   }else{
      if(previousValue === currentValue){
          alert('the text is the same');
      }else{
          alert('the text is different');
      }
   }
   previousValue = currentValue;

   //I thought maybe you'd want to clear the textfield after the user submits as well;
   document.getElementById("mytext").value = ""; //just a suggestion
}
```